npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @wordpress/components@^12.5.0
I am trying to create a Gutenberg block and have issues compiling it. I get this error when I run the following command. Can anyone help me in fixing the issue or atleast suggest/tell me what to do next or point me in right direction?
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

error: 
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @wordpress/components@^12.5.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

The package.json content:
  "dependencies": {
    "@wordpress/blocks": "^12.5.0",
    "@wordpress/element": "^12.5.0",
    "@wordpress/components": "^12.5.0",
    "@wordpress/block-editor": "^12.5.0",
    "@wordpress/i18n": "^12.5.0",
    "@wordpress/data": "^12.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^24.0.0"
  }

I have also tried using the following in package.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "@wordpress/blocks": "^23.0.0",
    "@wordpress/element": "^23.0.0",
    "@wordpress/components": "^23.0.0",
    "@wordpress/block-editor": "^23.0.0",
    "@wordpress/i18n": "^23.0.0",
    "@wordpress/data": "^23.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^24.0.0"
  }

My npm version is: 8.19.4 and node version: v16.20.2
